# Fetch random data from database without refreshing page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database, wordpress

i need some help, i have the following code:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tutorial ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$title = $result["title"];
$text = $result["text"];
$id = $result["id"];
```

I'm using this variables (`$title,$text,$id`) in different parts of html.
Also, i need this data when i load page, and when i press the "refresh without refresh page" button.
If some one can explain to me how i can fetch again a random data without refreshing the page, will be awesome :))

Comment: Read about ajax

Comment: Ajax is what you need to read about: learn more here http://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

Comment: Yes, but i need this variables in different parts of html and when i load page also after pressing the refresh button again need this random var.

Comment: @Mueyiwa Moses Ikomi try to avoid referencing w3schools it is prone to errors and misinformation if you are pasting in a reference I recommend using the source files in this case the [jQuery Library](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: @happymacarts thanks for the suggestion, but don't you think its best he learns the inner working of regular js before delving to libraries like JQuery

Comment: @Mueyiwa Moses Ikomi he tagged the post with `jquery` but yes an understanding of javascript would be better my point was avoiding w3schools if you wanted to send him to a better source [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started). Not downing your response just trying to improve the overall community and quality of responses. :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a file random_tutorials.php and make it every time you refresh to get a random tutorial. Style it as you want.

Next on page where you want to load it, create a div with id="rand_tut"
Then add a button with id="button" and add code below. Dont forget to load jquery first.
You need to make an Ajax call, maybe with jQuery

```
<script>
    $("#button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({url: "random_tutorials.php", success: function(result){
            $("#rand_tut").html(result);
        }});
    });
</script>
```

Working example: 
http://codepen.io/kkoutoup/details/zxmGLE/

Another simple
http://jsfiddle.net/t35F9/1/

Comment: Yes, already tried, but this variables are in different parts, of html. also it will not load this random variables from the first load of page.

Comment: thx dude, 1st example were interesting, but how i said first:
1. I need this variables on diffent parts of html.

Comment: @igor post your html so we can see what it is you need since this doesn't answer it for you